# Display LineFunction2D in JFreeChart

Tags: java, function, jfreechart

`JFreeChart` has a class called `LineFunction2D(double YIntercept, double Slope)`. I can get the `JFreeChart` examples to work, but I can't get `LineFunction2D` to work. How can I add the line graph to a `JFreeChart` object?

```
LineFunction2D line = new LineFunction2D(.03125, (.125 - .03125));

//missing code goes here

JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(Plot plot);
ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
```

Thanks!

(I'm working on the sscce, and will post it soon.)

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the code you are looking for is the call to `DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D` to convert the dataset into am `XYDataset` that you can add to your plot

```
private static final double A = 5 / 16d;
private static final double B = 1 / 8d - A;
private double start = 1;
private double end = 10;
private int samples = 4;
private Comparable<String> seriesKey = "Regression";
```

...

```
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(this.data1, xAxis, yAxis, renderer1);
        LineFunction2D line = new LineFunction2D(A, B);
        XYDataset lineDS = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(line,start,end,samples,seriesKey );
        plot.setDataset(plot.getDatasetCount() + 1, lineDS);
```

Comment: GrahamA, you're awesome! I think I get it all except one part. What do I do for the XYItemRenderer argument in the XYPlot constructor?

Comment: Use the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1707), Paul. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but also consider the value of named constants instead of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants). For example,

```
private static final double A = 5 / 16d;
private static final double B = 1 / 8d - A;
...
LineFunction2D line = new LineFunction2D(A, B);
```